# In what sense do isomorphisms "preserve all logical properties"?

Tags: logic, soft-question, set-theory, model-theory, meta-math

My background in mathematical logic, model theory, etc. is patchy, so I'm looking for a clearer way to think about this. (Edit: I'm not asking what an isomorphism is, I'm asking how to formalize the idea of "preserving all logical properties" in order to state the principle described below in its full power.)

Motivating example: we know that $\Bbb N$ and $\Bbb Z$ are not order-isomorphic, because $\Bbb N$ has a least element whereas $\Bbb Z$ does not. The principle underlying this argument seems to be that an order isomorphism preserves the truth values of (first-order) sentences: if $(A,<_A)\cong(B,<_B)$ then $\operatorname{Th}(A,<_A)=\operatorname{Th}(B,<_B)$. Since the property "there is a least element" corresponds to the sentence $\exists x\forall y. x\le y$, the principle applies. The principle also seems to apply to higher-order properties. For example, we can conclude that $(\Bbb R\setminus\{0\},<)\not\cong(\Bbb R,<)$ by checking the least-upper-bound property, which is second-order.

More generally (if we think of set theory as modeling higher-order logic in first-order logic), I'm tempted to claim that the whole "set theory of <" (I'm not sure what this is exactly - a two-sorted first-order logic with relation symbols $<,\in$, maybe?) is preserved by isomorphisms. I think I can convince myself of this fact by observing that when $f:A\to B$ is an isomorphism, certain substitution rules involving $f$ in various syntactic contexts are valid, allowing us to prove equivalences between propositions about $<_A$ and the corresponding propositions about $<_B$.

I'm calling this a "principle" instead of a "theorem" because it seems easier to apply in specific cases (by reasoning directly about the elements and the isomorphism, without formalizing the notion of sentences) than to express in its full generality. My claim that "the set theory of $<$ is preserved" seems closely related to the fact that set theory is my metatheory (if that's the right word), so some kind of circularity or self-reference is appearing when I attempt to state the principle, and I wonder whether any formal version of the principle can fully eliminate the need to apply the principle directly.

So I guess my questions are:

- In what sense (if any) is there a most general version of this principle, applying to all properties preserved by order isomorphisms?
- Can it be expressed as a theorem in the deductive system where we want to apply it, or is there a theoretical obstacle to this?
- Am I getting anything wrong? Or missing a clarifying perspective?

Thanks!

Comment: Someone will soon jump and tell you that you want to look up category theory or type theory. But in fact, you only need to look up the definition of truth in a structure and to understand how a bijection also induces a bijection between iterated power sets, Cartesian products, etc. to understand why isomorphisms preserve truth like that.

Comment: I think some clarification is needed about what you mean by "statements" or "theorems." If you're in a category $A$ then there's no reason for theorems pertaining to some other category $B$ should be preserved by the isomorphisms in $A.$ For example, homotopy equivalent CW complexes don't necessarily have the same dimension, whereas homeomorphic CW complexes do.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here is an outline of a theorem which, I think, addresses the situation pretty well (incidentally, [this MO question](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/336191/cauchy-reals-and-dedekind-reals-satisfy-the-same-mathematical-theorems) is related):

Most logic books will include a proof that first-order logic is isomorphism-invariant. But what about *non-first-order* properties? For example, the isomorphism-invariance of (say) Archimedeanness in the context of ordered fields is not a mere case of the isomorphism-invariance of first-order logic, even though "obviously" it holds for exactly the same reason.

There is in fact a framework for extending isomorphism-invariance from first-order logic to all "reasonable" logics, in a precise sense. The logics beyond first-order logic that we actually consider are really just "first-order logic in a superstructure." E.g. saying that a relation $R$ is definable over a structure $\mathcal{A}$ in monadic second-order logic is the same as saying that it is definable over $\mathcal{A}\sqcup\mathcal{P}(\mathcal{A})$ (being a bit vague about what that is, in the interest of brevity) in first-order logic.

This motivates the following idea. Working in $\mathsf{ZFC}$, let $V$ as usual denote the whole set-theoretic universe. There is a standard machinery for developing, first-order-definably inside $V$, a "version of $V$ with urelements" where the urelements correspond to elements of a given structure; the details are a bit tedious, but see e.g. [Barwise's book](https://projecteuclid.org/ebooks/perspectives-in-logic/admissible-sets-and-structures-an-approach-to-definability-theory/toc/pl/1235418470). Call the resulting object "$V_\mathcal{A}$." Being a bit sloppy about set/class issues, we can prove in $\mathsf{ZFC}$ that $\mathcal{A}\cong\mathcal{B}$ implies $V_\mathcal{A}\cong V_\mathcal{B}$. This, together with the fact that isomorphism preserves *first-order* truth, gives the following result:

> Isomorphisms preserve truth with respect to every "set-theoretically-definable" logic.

Here the idea is that each sentence $\varphi$ in a set-theoretically-definable logic should correspond to a first-order sentence $\hat{\varphi}$ such that $$\mathcal{A}\models\varphi\quad\iff\quad V_\mathcal{A}\models\hat{\varphi}$$ (or at worst, a first-order sentence $\hat{\varphi}$ with a parameter from $V$ - note that $V$ sits inside $V_\mathcal{A}$ in a canonical way, so a single $V$-parameter makes sense across all $V_\mathcal{A}$s independently of $\mathcal{A}$; we need to allow parameters to handle logics with "too many sentences," such as infinitary logic).

So what we have here is a way to "bootstrap" the isomorphism-invariance of first-order truth to all logics *which are set-theoretically definable in a precise sense*.

I'm skipping a **lot** of detail in the above, since quite frankly it's rather tedious. If you're interested, let me know and I'll expand on this. But I think it is worth mentioning, even if only very briefly, the existence of a precise theorem of the above type.

Comment: There's an interesting meta-question here - is there, in any reasonable sense, a logic which is not "first-order relative to some superstructure"? It's difficult for me to see how one would possibly make a positive case for this, but I'd be interested in pointers to the literature if this has been treated before. My own take on the situation is that everything has to fall back onto first-order logic eventually, at some level, but that's just me.

Comment: Thanks! If I'm understanding correctly, this $V_\cal A$ with urelements models the two-sorted logic I imagined for "the set theory of" the structure, and the theorem $\cal A\cong\cal B\implies V_\cal A\cong V_\cal B$ says (model-theoretically) that isomorphisms preserve this theory, as well as truth in any logic whose sentences can be faithfully translated into this theory.

Comment: @Karl Yup, that's basically it.

Comment: Cool, this seems like a great answer to my first question. I wonder if I should ask the second question separately - I think I'm mixing up a concern about "applying the theorem to the system that the theorem is about" (possibly related to Tarski's undefinability theorem?) with the problem of characterizing all preserved logical properties.

Comment: @Karl This is in fact already a theorem, or rather a theorem *scheme* (that is, a collection of theorems presented in a uniform way); we can get a genuine one-for-all theorem if we work in $\mathsf{NBG}$ as opposed to $\mathsf{ZFC}$. It applies to first-order logic, which is the logic of the theory in which it's proved, without issue. So there aren't subtleties here, at least if I understand your second question correctly. (Aside, Tarski undefinability is a very specific obstacle and doesn't seem relevant here.)

Comment: Interesting! So if I'm working in $\mathsf{NBG}$ and want to apply this isomorphism principle in order to prove a statement of the form $A\cong B\implies(\phi(A)\iff\phi(B))$ (where $\phi$ is of the form such that the principle applies), I can do so by instantiating this theorem *about* $\mathsf{NBG}$ with an appropriate term that represents $\phi$?

Comment: @Karl I don't understand what the "about $\mathsf{NBG}$" is doing there. $\mathsf{NBG}$ is the setting within which this theorem, and the argument using it, take place. The general shape would be: you have (say) some non-first-order sentence $\varphi$, and you want to show that $\varphi$ is isomorphism invariant - that is, that $$\forall\mathcal{A},\mathcal{B}(\mathcal{A}\models\varphi\iff\mathcal{B}\models\varphi).$$ You produce a first-order sentence $\psi$, and prove - in $\mathsf{NBG}$ - that $$\forall\mathcal{X}(\mathcal{X}\models \varphi\iff V_\mathcal{X}\models\psi).$$ (cont'd)

Comment: Next, you prove - in $\mathsf{NBG}$ - that $$\forall \mathcal{X,Y}(\mathcal{X}\cong\mathcal{Y}\implies V_\mathcal{X}\cong V_\mathcal{Y}),$$ and subsequently by applying isomorphism invariance of first-order logic you get the desired result. At no point was there any "self-application" business - $\mathsf{NBG}$, or whatever, was just the system in which we're proving our goal.

Comment: Ah, I said "about $\mathsf{NBG}$" because I was thinking of $\phi$ as a formula in the language of $\mathsf{NBG}$ and I wanted the result "natively". Maybe the point I overlooked is something like: $\mathsf{NBG}$ (or $\mathsf{ZFC}$ with schemes) can talk natively about its own formulas (as classes), so the theorem at hand, at least as it applies to sentences in the logic of $\mathsf{NBG}$, can be stated and proved (as "$\forall \varphi...$") without "encoding" syntactic sentences or deductive systems at all. I need to think more about how that would work.

Comment: Or maybe I'm just wrong in assuming there's something problematic about working with encoded sentences. For any $\varphi$, the equivalence between $\cal A\models\varphi$ and the corresponding "native" proposition (that looks like $\varphi$ but has some extra "$v\in A$" stuff) presumably follows directly from the definition of $\models$. This is where I should stop wasting your time and just look a few things up :) Thanks again!

Comment: @NoahSchweber: About your first comment, doesn't it just boil down to the belief (which I also subscribe to) that every structure we can conceive of can ultimately be expressed reasonably well as some first-order structure? Or, equivalently, is there some structure that is so alien that it is actually (mentally) painful to think of it in first-order terms? I don't think so; after all as you noted we can think of full SOL structures as being FOL structures over a domain and its (full) power-set relative to the meta-system. And I suppose you don't think so either. Right?

Comment: @user21820 Short version, yes. But on a meta-level, I try to keep a lookout for ways in which I could miss seeing something spectacularly weird. It's hard to explain why, but "everything is 'ultimately' first-order," while something I do completely buy, triggers my weirdness-opportunity-detector to the point that I at least don't want to push it as uncontroversial fact.

Comment: @NoahSchweber: Yea I get that. Thanks for explaining! =)

Answer (score 4):

If $\mathbf{M_1}$ and $\mathbf{M_2}$ are structures for some signature $\Sigma$ (so $\Sigma = (<)$) in your example. Then, by definition, $\mathbf{M_1}$ and $\mathbf{M_2}$ are isomorphic iff there are functions $f : M_1 \to M_2$ and $g : M_2 \to M_1$ (where $M_i$ is the universe of discourse of $\mathbf{M_i}$), such that $g \circ f = 1_{M_1}$ and $g \circ f = 1_{M_2}$ and such that $f$ and $g$ are **homomorphisms** for the relations and functions in $\Sigma$ (so, in your example, $x < y$ iff $f(x) < g(y)$ and $u < v$ iff $g(u) < g(v)$). So if $\mathbf{M_1}$ and $\mathbf{M_2}$ are isomorphic, a logical language $\cal L$ (first-order or higher-order) over the signature $\Sigma$ cannot distinguish between $\mathbf{M_1}$ and $\mathbf{M_2}$, since $f$ induces a truth-preserving mapping from interpretations of $\cal L$ in  $\mathbf{M_1}$ and interpretations of $\cal L$ in $\mathbf{M_2}$ (and vice versa for $g$).

Comment: Thanks! I suppose we'd prove by induction on formula length that the induced mapping between interpretations is truth-preserving; maybe this formalizes my reasoning about "substitution rules involving $f$". I'm interested in whether the theorem you've stated, which we might formalize in ZFC and which applies to a fixed $\cal L$ (modeled as an object in ZFC), "covers all possible logical properties" that are provably (in ZFC) preserved by order isomorphisms. Am I wrong to expect a self-reference problem here?

Comment: What self-reference problem could there be?

Comment: I guess I have a feeling there could be a sentence $A\cong B\implies(\phi(A)\iff\phi(B))$, saying that isomorphisms preserve property $\phi$, that's provable in ZFC but is not a case of the theorem that formalizes the principle. Am I just instantiating a theorem within ZFC every time I apply the principle (e.g. to prove that $(\Bbb N,<) \ncong(\Bbb Z,<)$), or am I necessarily appealing to a bit of "meta" reasoning? The general principle seems to be second-order ("$\forall\phi...$"), and my vague understanding is that set theory simulates higher-order logic but loses something in the process.

Comment: Now that I think about it, it's clear that any $\phi$ I can come up with occurs as a formula for which your theorem has a corresponding instance (assuming $\cal L$ has $\in$). But going from $A\models\phi\iff B\models\phi$ to $\phi(A)\iff\phi(B)$ is a "meta" step in some sense, right? What's the right way to think about that?

Comment: Actually maybe my previous comment is nonsense. I'm confused.

Comment: I think you are "overthinking" this. Isomorphisms preserve all properties that the language we are using to describe a system can state.

Comment: Yeah, this informally-stated fact about isomorphisms is clear enough. But let's say I'm formalizing some order theory in a proof-checking tool like Lean. Can I prove this fact once and then just instantiate it wherever it's needed?

Comment: That's dependent on your choices as to how you formalise the theory and on the support for polymorphic or generic properties that the logic of your proof assistant supports.