# In what sense does a basis isomorphism "reduce" everything to a question in $\mathbb{F}^n$?

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

Before starting a long chapter called "Computations Concerning Subspaces" which talks about answering questions about row space dimension, linear independence, etc., Hoffman and Kunze (HK) write:

> "The discussion applies to any $n$-dimensional vector space over the field $\mathbb{F}$, if one selects a fixed ordered basis $B$ and describes each vector $\alpha$ in $V$ by the n-tuple $(x_i,.., x_n)$ which gives the coordinates of $\alpha$ the ordered basis $B$."

Now I know intuitively that the existence of an isomorphism between $\mathbb{F}^n$ and $V$ means that "thing $x$ true in $V$ if and only if the corresponding thing $x'$ is true in $\mathbb{F}^n$", but is there any way to make this precise?

One example of a question in $\mathbb{F}^n$ which we can ask per HK is

> How does one determine if the vectors $\{\alpha_i \in \mathbb{F}^n\}$, are linearly independent? More generally, how does one find the dimension of the subspace $W$ spanned by these vectors?

Naturally, we can think of asking the same question in some $n$-dimensional $V$:

> How does one determine if the vectors $\{\alpha_i \in V\}$, are linearly independent? More generally, how does one find the dimension of the subspace $W$ spanned by these vectors?

Let me call $T_B$ the isomorphism between $V$ and $\mathbb{F}^n$ which obtains from fixing a given basis $B$ of $V$ and taking the coordinates of any vector in that basis. The answer here I suppose, is to use that $\{\alpha_i \in V\}$ is l.i. iff $\{ T_B\alpha_i \in \mathbb{F}^n \}$ is l.i. and so on.

Is there a way of phrasing (at the level of Hoffman and Kunze) more precisely what HK say, or do I have to prove specific theorems which "translate" to $\mathbb{F}^n$ for each question which may come up about subspaces of $V$?

Comment: Possibly related: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4058319

Comment: Thanks for linking @Karl I will consult it. At a first glance, it seems way above my head, but perhaps I'll glean something from it. I suppose I was wondering if there were any elementary (within finite-dim vector spaces) statements to made.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several ways of making this precise. There is a similar question [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4246026/798694) which I’ve answered giving an extremely broad class of statements which are isomorphism-invariant.

Essentially, there are a few “bad” kinds of statements that are not isomorphism-invariant. For example, “Is $47$ an element of $V$?” is a bad question. However, there is a way of systematically listing “good” questions, which is to make everything “typed”. Asking whether $47$ is an element of $V$ is not well-typed. Similarly, if we have sets $A, B$ and elements $a \in A$, $b \in B$, the question “Does $a = b$?” is also not well-typed. If it were, we could just ask the question “Does there exist $a \in A$ such that $a = 47$?”, which we already declared is a “bad” question.

The good news is that all interesting mathematical statements outside of set theory are well-typed (and there’s even an algorithm for taking statements in set theory and transforming them into an provably equivalent well-typed statement). We can even build our foundation of mathematics so that every question we can pose is automatically well-typed; these foundations can be made to have the same proof-theoretic power as normal ZFC set theory. These foundations are called “structural set theories”, and the most well-known version is ETCS, which is the Elementary Theory of the Category of Sets (and is based on category theory). Another approach is SEAR, which axiomatises Sets, Elements, And Relations.

There’s an even more radical approach which involves declaring isomorphic things to actually be equal. This approach is taken in Homotopy Type Theory (HoTT), and there are a lot of subtleties - in particular, two objects isomorphic in more than one way can be equal in more than one way, and which way they’re equal matters. HoTT allows us to take any property or data and “transport” it along an equality from one object to another. There’s a fair amount of exciting research going on in this area, since it lies at the intersection of computability, category theory, and homotopy theory.

Comment: This is *way* above my head, but very cool. I suppose at my lowly level I will need to restrict myself to proving the relevant equivalences as they come up, but it is good to know this all exists.